# variable declaration (implicit and explicit and advantages & disadvantages)

Tags: variable-declaration

"What are explicit declaration & implicit declaration of variables in programming language concepts  and their advantages and disadvantages?"

Answer (score 3):

Explicit variable declaration means that the type of the variable is declared before or when the variable is set. Implicit variable declaration means the type of the variable is assumed by the operators, but any data can be put in it.

In C,
`int x = 5; printf(x-5); x = "test"; printf(x-5);`
returns a compile time error when you set x to test

but in Python,
`x = 5; print(x-5); x = "test"; print(x-5);`
will "compile" (python doesn't compile, but it will run the program) and give you a runt time error when you try to subtract from the string.

One advantage of Implicit variables is that it makes it easier to write code without worrying about the behind the scenes data type, the compiler should pick the appropriate one based on its future usage.

Another advantage is that you can flexibly type a variable to hold different things that may not even share a parent class. Doing this is risky, as you have no guarantees that the objects will be interpreted correctly by following code.

One disadvantage is that Implicit variables have no guarantees of what they are. A function that computes the difference between two numbers will not return an compile time error if the variables have strings in them. You passed in two variables, it is up to you to ensure they are the right type. It also makes reading code harder in some ways. `var nextLocation = LeftHandedSmokeShifter(3.3)` is completely legitimate code, but You have to look up the function to even guess what it is doing. `string nextLocation  = LeftHandedSmokeShifter(3.3)` at least tells me that I should be using the output for mathematical operations.

Type heavy languages are always explicitly declared and typed, but type weak languages are mostly implicitly typed. If you can set a variable to "Var" it is likely an implicitly typed language.

Answer (score 2):

An explicit declaration is when you start making the variable by order it first.
ex: String name; name="yourname"; 
the advantages is you be able to fill your variable with any algorithm or math logic to make a value. the disadvantages is when you use it as a material without fill the value of your variable ,there will be an error.

An implicit declaration is when you make a variable directly without order it first. ex : String name="yourname";
the advantages : it is a practically treatment at some condition.

.

Comment: I think that is not correct and misleading. The other ansewr from Malsha got it right.

Answer (score 2):

Explicit means declaring variable like in c.
Implicit declaration in variable declaration in python.
In Explicit we should cast.
In implicit no need of casting.